# Dijit.menu how to find out which node was clicked

Tags: dojo

I connect dijit.Menu to many nodes:

```
      var result = dojo.query(".progMenu");

       pMenu = new dijit.Menu({
            targetNodeIds:result
       });
```

When I click on a node from result the menu is displayed.
I would like to find out which node from result array was clicked, when I select some item from shown menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   var result = dojo.query(".progMenu");

   var pMenu = new dijit.Menu({
            targetNodeIds:result,
            onClick: function(event) {
               var node = event.target;
            }
       });
```

Answer (score 1):

What about something like that instead ?

```
pMenu = new dijit.Menu({});

dojo.query(".progMenu").forEach(function(node){
    pMenu.addChild(new dijit.MenuItem({
        onClick: function(){
            // do some behaviour, and access node with "node"
            console.log("my node : ", node);
        }
    }, node));
}, this);
```

Not sure the code work as is, but it is just to give you a hint.
It might also depend on your dojo version !

Hope this helps :)